# Perdi a senha de administrador do Glassfish

Tags: glassfish

Perdi a senha da conta admin do Glassfish, como devo proceder? Para atualizar a senha eu preciso da senha antiga, que perdi. Tem como mexer diretamente nos arquivos para resetar?

Comment: Esse link resolve? https://documentacao.senior.com.br/bancodesolucoes/acesso-seguranca/5091.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O único meio que encontrei até hoje é alterando o arquivo de configuração chamado `admin-keyfile` que fica em:

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME$\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\admin-keyfile
```

Remova o conteúdo (ou somente comente o conteúdo), substituindo por esse abaixo:

```
admin;{SSHA}WQVj8i9CLECCiv+w6ZxGgMrcfPqHPoXZW+2Jdw==;asadmin
```

Com isso, a senha será resetada para o default, que é não ter senha.